# PHP preg_replace shortening a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So I've got this php code:

```
$text = preg_replace("/(\s)http:\/\/([\S]+?)(\s)/i" , 
"$1[url=\"http://$2\"]http://$2[/url]$3" , " $text ");
```

I guess it's replacing `http://xyz.xyz.xyz` kind of strings into `[url=http://xyz.xyz.xyz]http://xyz.xyz.xyz[/url]` inside of a given text (in my case it's a postparser for my forum) right?

now what I'm trying to do is, to limit the stringlength of the `http://xyz.xyz.xyz`-string that comes inside the `[url=http://xyz.xyz.xyz]` `http://xyz.xyz.xyz` <-- this string `[/url]`
because sometimes users post very long links and those are messing up my forum design and look very ugly anyway.

is there a way I could realize that in php, while keeping the 1. http link like it is so it still links correct?

big thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$text = preg_replace("/(\s)http:\/\/([\S]{,40})([\S]*?)(\s)/i",
"$1[url=\"http://$2$3\"]http://$2[/url]$4" , " $text ");
```

to limit it to a 40 character URL?

Comment: Matches `$2` and `$3` together comprise the whole URL and that's what goes into the href attribute of the link.

Comment: this didnt work :( it just gave out the whole url without any modification

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe just split the process in a couple of lines of code instead of one do-it-all preg_replace.

1. preg_match
2. check strlen for match
3. shorten url between [url][/url] if need
4. build replacement string
5. str_replace match with replacement string

Comment: i tried that, but the problem i had was that i could separate the link from the whole posttext for further modification. and i sense a problem when i need to put the correct [url] string back in its place. strlen and modifications to the string are no problem for me though.

Comment: @Yunga. preg_match will provide you with the matches, you can work on the results and do a search and replace after that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_replace_callback` so that you have more control over the replacement. (e.g. use `$2` in `[url=...]` and use a shorten version of `$2` in the text.

```
function replace_links($matches) {

    $url = $matches[2];
    $short_url = preg_replace('~^([^/]*)/(.{14})(.{3,})(.{18})$~', '$1/$2...$4', $url);

    return $matches[1] . '[url="http://' . $url . '"]http://' . $short_url . '[/url]' . $matches[3];

}

$text = preg_replace_callback("/(\s)http:\/\/([\S]+?)(\s)/i", 'replace_links', " $text ");
```

[(Codepad)](http://codepad.org/knQ4N80s)

You can see that I use another `preg_replace` for transforming a very long URL to a short one. I cut it in the middle, while fully preserving the domain name, but you may use any cutting pattern you want.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, i like it.